# jQuery detect input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a feature where the user needs to be informed that there are unsaved changes in a form in case if they decide to navigate away from the page.

I am almost done but there's a tiny problem-

I am setting a boolean `dirty` on input change event.

The `.change()` event will detect any kind of change, as in it doesn't keep track of changes. For example, if an input field has the original value `hello`, which is modified to `bye` and back to `hello`, it will still set the `dirty` boolean.

Is there any way where I can take a backup of the form with initial values and then compare it with itself at every change event?

Comment: I think you've to store each initial input values and compare them with the new changement and if it's different only put dirty as true.

Comment: Store the initial values inside the `localStorage` object?

Comment: Save original value in `hidden fields` and check with current values when user tries to navigate away?

Comment: You can compare with the element's `defaultValue` property

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to serialize the form data into a JSON object, and then you could either compare the JSON object by iterating the properties or by comparing the `JSON.stringify` values.

I have slightly modified the method of objectifying the form data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/5894241) in order to do this.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
var originalFormData = objectifyForm(form);
var originalFormDataString = JSON.stringify(originalFormData);

setInterval(function() {
  var formData = objectifyForm(form);
  var formDataString = JSON.stringify(formData);
  console.log("Form is dirty: " + (formDataString != originalFormDataString));
},1000);

function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function

  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
    returnArray[formArray[i]['id']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <input id="myInput" value="test" type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Remember this solution is just a sample. You have multiple input element, than use array/object to save there defaultValue.

```js
 var defaultValue = document.getElementById("myText").defaultValue;//Get the default value

 var handleChange = function (){
    let value =  document.getElementById("myText").value;//get the current value
    if(defaultValue===value){
       console.log("dirty false")
    }else {
       console.log("Dirty True")
    }
 
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="abc" onkeyup="handleChange()">
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a javascript empty initial_values = {} object. initialised it with the default values in the form of key:value pairs. and if dirty boolean is set, it can be used to compare later on.